# When I copied text from Azure Cloud Shell terminal , copied string is incomplete

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

I selected bellow area and pressed `command+C`.

[cloud shell capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjNoR.png)

Following string is pasted from my clipboard.

> You are viewing an offline list of runtimes. For up to dat

My browser is `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36`

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation.

**Note:** FireFox/IE may not support clipboard permissions properly.

For more details, refer "[Limitations of Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/limitations)".

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome for Mac. Is it also limited by clipboard permission ?

Comment: This shouldn't occur for Chrome - could you verify this repros across other browsers and what type of OS you are running? Could you also tell us where you are using cloud shell from (portal/shell.azure/docs/etc.)?

Comment: I wrote user-agent string in this post.
`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36`

Comment: > Could you also tell us where you are using cloud shell from (portal/shell.azure/docs/etc.)?

1. I logged in "https://portal.azure.com" with my user account.
2. I clicked ">_" button that placed at header navi.

Then, the Azure Cloud Shell was launched bottom of screen.

Comment: In the case of using `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0 `, it did not reproduced.